# Show coordinates LAT / LONG Google Maps - Track Markers Busses of External Website

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, canvas, gps

I'm looking for a way to show the coordinates **LAT / LONG of the Bus (Markers)** of a particular bus line shown on Google Maps, but I can not extract this information from the site. I used Firebug and have not found the Coordinates LAT / LONG.

**The address for the url I'm trying to extract LAT / LONG is:**

http://olhovivo.sptrans.com.br/#sp?cat=Mapa&l=34694&s=857P-10&sc=TERMINAL%20CAMPO%20LIMPO

(.. OR ..)

http://olhovivo.sptrans.com.br/#sp?cat=Mapa&l=829&s=9789-10&sc=BARRA%20FUNDA&nc

I want to use a **script Javascript** to capture Coordinates  (LAT / LONG). I'm trying the 
following code in Firebug console:

**javascript:void(prompt("TEST",gApplication.getMap().getCenter()));**

, but it only works on URLs that have the domain GoogleMaps.

Have any tip or trick to help extract the Long / Lat objects (bus) on Google Map?

Which adjustments do you recommend? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: You know that the lat/long coordinates of the bus is copyrighted Material from SP Trans?

Comment: It is for private use, then do not infringe on any copyright, because I will not be selling the information to anyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the prettiest thing in the world, but the coordinates ARE inside the link in the map to "*Click to see this area on Google Maps*", so if you grab that link you can work some magic. For example, copy/paste this into Firebug and you should get what you're looking for...

```
var x=($('a[title="Click to see this area on Google Maps"]').attr("href")); x.split("?ll=")[1].split("&z")[0];
```

Good luck! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But here it did not work. Have you tried on your computer and showed the coordinates Lat / Long? Please, could test the site later, because of the Time Zone may have no bus traveling at the time you test. I'm in Brazil and the URL is the city São Paulo. You can see the coordinates Lat / Long of the site using your tip? Or is that the coordinates are stored on the company server? Obs: Hence 5 hours the bus will be on the streets again... Thanks...

Comment: Yes, it works. Copy the entire command into the console. Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/jD1xmD8.gif It works by finding the link with the title "Click to see this area on Google Maps". Maybe your map is showing that link with it's Portuguese title because you're in Brazil? Rewrite the Jquery and replace the title with whatever that says in Portuguese. Or better yet, get the link by the style using this code: `var x=($('a[style="position: static; overflow: visible; float: none; display: inline;"]').attr("href")); x.split("?ll=")[1].split("&z")[0];`

Comment: Perfect! Now the new code is working! Thank you! PS: You know very well jQuery. Congratulations!

Comment: Excellent! Glad to help. If you could upvote the answer and "Accept it as Answer", it will get the checkmark and show it as the answer. That way anybody else who sees this will know it's right!

Comment: Ok I'm new on this forum, and do not know the ins and outs of using the Portal, but I'll be doing what you asked. Thank you.

Comment: Hello! Your tip shows only Coordinated Central on the map, but I need the coordinates of the markers (Bus) individually. Example: Bus 001 - Lat: XXX... Long: XXX..., Bus 002 - Lat: XXX... Long XXX... and so on. You know the trick to get this information from the Map using JQuery? Using the Google Maps APIs will have access to this data?